# How to properly use GET requests in Redux with React hooks?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-functional-component

I'm currently trying to implement a GET request inside a Redux reducer and use the result inside a React functional component, here's what I have so far:

My Users.tsx reducer (Only the relevant call, the rest of the file is the standard format you'd expect from a reducer):

```
 export function getUsers() {
  return(dispatch: any) => {
    dispatch(requestUsers());
    fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        (result) => {
          dispatch(receiveUsers(result));
        }
      )
  }
}
```

And here's my functional component:

```
  export const Home: React.FC = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const userList: UserData = useSelector((state: any) => state.users.users);

  console.log("rendered", userList);

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getUsers());
  }, [])

  return (
    <IonContent>
      {userList && (userList.data.map((user) => (
        <IonCard key={user.id}>
          <IonCardHeader>
            <IonCardTitle className="ion-text-center">{user.first_name} {user.last_name}</IonCardTitle>
          </IonCardHeader>
          <IonCardContent className="ion-text-center">
            <p>{user.email}</p>
          </IonCardContent>
        </IonCard>
      )))
      }
    </IonContent>
  )
}

export default Home;
```

It is working right now but the component is rendered 3 times (2 with `userList` undefined) as opposed from the 2 I'd expect (Once when the component is first loaded and once after the user info is received), is this normal behaviour? Otherwise why does the third render happen?

What I'm trying to achieve is a functional component that uses a Redux dispatch function to call an API and then render after the results are in, is this the correct way to implement it?

Comment: you need to check the profiler for that. But you don't have to worry about the third rerender as you have already fetched your data in the second and updated the components with it. So, third rerender may b updating lot less code. So, if you component is behaving nicely you dont't have to worry about the rerenders. Generally rerenders are not slow but the heavy computational functions in a component are making the rerenders slow. But in your case you don't have any.

Comment: you should be using a middleware in redux as redux can't handle asynchronouses, it has to be pure objects that you dispatch. Give a read on redux-thunk or redux-saga to get a grasp on it.